# Prevent alert dialog from dismissing when you click out of it

Tags: android

I'm implementing a pawn promotion for a chess app. When the pawn reaches the end of the board, an alert dialog comes up with 4 items representing chess peices the pawn can be promoted to. The problem is, the alert dialog can be dismissed if you click outside of it and the pawn ends up not being promoted which is illegal.

How can I solve this issue? I've tried deregistering the listeners on the buttons behind the alert dialog but It still does not work.

Comment: Post the question with description and also add some code

Comment: @EngrWaseemArain It doesn't need code. You're just too lazy to read. It's okay someone answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: Not working for AlertDialog